# Reorder array based on condition lodash

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I have a collection like so:

```
var scores = [{
    name: foo,
    score: 34
}, {
    name: bar,
    score: 23
}, {
    name: baz,
    score: 99
}]
```

I also have a variable containing a name:

```
var selfName = 'bar';
```

How can I rearrange scores collection such that the object containing selfName is at index 0. Expected result :

```
[{
    name: bar,
    score: 23
}, {
    name: foo,
    score: 34
}, {
    name: baz,
    score: 99
}]
```

I know I can do it by:

```
var isSelfName = (selfName, score) => {
        var _name = selfName; 
        return (score) => {
        return score.name === selfName;    
    }
};
var result = _.filter(scores, isSelfName(selfName));
result.push(_.reject(scores, isSelfName(selfName)));
result = _.flatten(result);
console.log('result:', result);
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could sort it with [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and a comparison result as order value.

```js
var scores = [{ name: 'foo', score: 34 }, { name: 'bar', score: 23 }, { name: 'baz', score: 99 }],
    selfName = 'bar';

scores.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.name !== selfName) - (b.name !== selfName);
});

console.log(scores);
```

Answer (score 4):

Excellent solution provided by **Nina**. But since you want to use `lodash` there is another alternative solution if you like to consider.

```js
var scores = [{ name: 'foo', score: 34 }, { name: 'bar', score: 23 }, { name: 'baz', score: 99 }],
    selfName = 'bar';

var temp = _.partition(scores, function(score) { return score.name === selfName; });

var result = _.concat(...temp);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And add ES6 spread  operator to make it more terse:
    var result = _.concat(...temp);

Answer (score 2):

Another `.sort` that works. I think the logic expression is a little more naturally intuitive than the expression used in Nina's sort.

```js
var scores = [
  { name: 'foo', score: 34 },
  { name: 'bar', score: 23 },
  { name: 'baz', score: 99 }
];

var selfName = 'bar';

scores.sort(({name:a}, {name:b}) => a === selfName || b === selfName);

console.log(scores);
```